# Windows Aero - Programmatically Disabling Visual Effects

Tags: winapi, accessibility, aero

Does anyone know how if there is an API to programmatically disable/enable specific Windows visual effects, like "Enable Transparent Glass" or "Enable Aero Peek" ?

The effects I am referring to are those configured in: System/Advanced System preferences/Advanced (tab)/Performance Settings/Custom

I am creating an accessibility tool for Windows and I need to disable some visual effects because they are "invisible"  for sight-impaired users. Also, I need to save some CPU cycles for the screen magnification and color adjustments.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

No, it can be disabled while a particular application is running using [`DwmEnableComposition()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969538%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Changing it globally is internal to windows and should really be done by the user.

Comment: AFIAK, DwmEnableComposition() disables Aero entirely, right? I need desktop composition, or the magnification api won't work....

Answer (score 2):

Aero themes makes troubles when BitBlting transparent png and other images. In Aero theme the transparency get screw when I use AlphaBlend instead BitBlt, and CPngImage in lieu of CBitmap, and set BLENDFUNCTION structure with some transparency from 0-255 in BLENDFUNCTION::SourceConstantAlpha. I use this approach when I want to have transparent background or merely fade as semitransparent (opacity 0-255)
And when Aero theme is on all transparency swept away. So I disable the aero theme transparency with DwmEnableComposition(DWM_EC_DISABLECOMPOSITION);

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
hr = DwmEnableComposition(DWM_EC_DISABLECOMPOSITION);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)){
    //  Aero theme effect is off! No more swept away transparency
}
```

just call it into OnInitDialog() or some earlier window instance function. That's do the trick