# BitBlt and ElementHost not working on some machines

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bitblt

This is a weird problem.

I'm using `BitBlt` to copy from the device context associated with my (WinForms) window handle to a bitmap, and it works (or so I thought).

But there's one machine where the WPF elements inside ElementHost just don't show up on the bitmap: there isn't a hole, it's just as if they were transparent and whatever is behind appears instead.

I've been playing around with one VM, one working and the other not. They both have the same OS version, I've whittled down the installed Programs and Features to be the same on both, and yet there is still one which works and the other not.

Has anyone come across this problem, and does anyone have any ideas where to start searching?

**UPDATE**: thanks to jsanalytics tip in the comment, I've worked out that it's Aero which stops the screenshot working properly. Now to work out why and what to do about it...

Comment: Take a look [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801997/bitblt-screen-capture-not-working-on-windows-10#comment82864127_47801997). I had suggested `GetLastWin32Error()` but never heard back from OP.

Comment: @jsanalytics, thanks. So I can confirm that it's Aero which makes the difference (off = works, on = doesn't work).

Comment: may I ask what is the error code you get?

Comment: @jsanalytics zero

Comment: Well... not helpful...:) Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Just one more thing: I'm assuming you got error code zero in the machine it does **not** work, right?

Comment: @jsanalytics, yes. [This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24816975/11410) seems to have had the same problem. I'm going to try disabling DWM.

Comment: That doesn't work either. Monster screen flicker and black image...

Answer (score 1):

This isn't *the* answer, but it's working for me for the moment:

If

```
[DllImport("dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
public static extern int DwmIsCompositionEnabled(out bool enabled);
```

Returns true, then instead of `BitBlt`ing the Device context of the window, I `BitBlt` the whole desktop, but crop to the size of the window (using `GetWindowRect` and adapting the created Bitmap to the size, then passing left and top into `BitBlt`).